# Associations of Hierarchical Objects, belongs_to, has_many of Own Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make objects belong to other objects of the same class by adding a `parent_id` attribute to the object so active record can associate them with each other in a hierarchical manner.

I know I can just write an instance method to do a find and get them, but I want to know if there is a more *rails appropriate* way to accomplish this, so can I set this up with active record associations, if so how?

Comment: This sounds kinda weird in principle. Can you show an example where that would apply ? Have you also tried using a standard has_many through ?

Comment: like nested comments, where i would want to find the object's parent and children. all objects are of the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this gem may be of help :

https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set

or acts_as_tree:

https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of nesting data in databases. The one to choose manly depends on how you are going to access this data, and how often you are going to change the tree.

Here is a list of current nesting plugins for rails: http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_nesting.html Be sure to reed each of the gems documentation in order to choose the most appropriate one for your situation.